# Docker compose generates anonymous volume rather then existing named volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-desktop

In order to keep track of the volumes used, i like to use named volumes. Currently i have one named volume

```
docker volume ls
DRIVER   VOLUME NAME
local    mongodb
```

my docker-compose file is something like this:

```
version: "3"

services: 
  db:
    image: mongo:4.0.6
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment: 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: macmongoroot
    volumes: 
      - mongodb:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb:
    external:
      name: mongodb

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: macbook
```

everytime i run docker-compose `docker-compose up -d` docker compose adds a new anonymous volume rather then using the named one :

```
docker volume ls
DRIVER     VOLUME NAME
local      a4a02fffa9bbbdd11c76359264a5bf24614943c5b1b0070b33a84e51266c58d7
local      mongodb
```

this docker compose file works fine on my server but on my docker desktop i'm having this issue. currently using Docker Desktop version 2.0.0.3 (31259). Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: what are the versions of your docker-compose programs? (`docker-compose version`)

Comment: @Thomasleveil i'm currently using docker-compose v 1.23.2, docker-machine v 0.16.1 and docker engine v 18.09.2

Comment: are those the versions found on your server or desktop? Are the same version on the server and desktop?

Comment: @Thomasleveil on my desktop. no the server version are bit more older

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anonymous volume belongs to `/data/configdb` which in the Dockerfile [instructions](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.0/Dockerfile#L90)

```
VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

By doing `docker inspect` on the created container you will notice the following:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "mongodb",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodb/_data",
                "Destination": "/data/db",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "be86274b1f6009eb60b8acb3855f51931c4ccc7df700666555422396688b0dd6",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/be86274b1f6009eb60b8acb3855f51931c4ccc7df700666555422396688b0dd6/_data",
                "Destination": "/data/configdb",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ]
```

Which means that `mongodb` volume is actually being used for the data as you asked however another volume will be created for this `/data/configdb`. Also you can verify that the data exist by checking this source path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodb/_data` where mongodb data will be saved

```
$ ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodb/_data                                                                            total 328
drwxr-xr-x 4  999  999  4096 Mar  8 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar  8 10:58 ..
-rw------- 1  999  999 16384 Mar  8 11:00 collection-0--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999 36864 Mar  8 11:01 collection-2--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999  4096 Mar  8 11:00 collection-4--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999 16384 Mar  8 11:00 collection-7--2358474299739251284.wt
drwx------ 2  999  999  4096 Mar  8 11:11 diagnostic.data
-rw------- 1  999  999 16384 Mar  8 11:00 index-1--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999 36864 Mar  8 11:01 index-3--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999  4096 Mar  8 10:58 index-5--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999  4096 Mar  8 11:01 index-6--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999 16384 Mar  8 10:58 index-8--2358474299739251284.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999 16384 Mar  8 10:58 index-9--2358474299739251284.wt
drwx------ 2  999  999  4096 Mar  8 11:00 journal
-rw------- 1  999  999 16384 Mar  8 11:00 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999     2 Mar  8 11:00 mongod.lock
-rw------- 1  999  999 36864 Mar  8 11:02 sizeStorer.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999   114 Mar  8 10:58 storage.bson
-rw------- 1  999  999    45 Mar  8 10:58 WiredTiger
-rw------- 1  999  999  4096 Mar  8 11:00 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw------- 1  999  999    21 Mar  8 10:58 WiredTiger.lock
-rw------- 1  999  999  1065 Mar  8 11:02 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw------- 1  999  999 69632 Mar  8 11:02 WiredTiger.wt
```

Comment: thanks that cleared why there's another volume,  but my issue still remains that every time i do a `docker-compose down` then do a `docker-compose up -d` seems like all my mongodb data is removed. later i'l try to do docker inspect and have it posted here.

Comment: The data wont be removed because they are on an external volume. I have tested it and I still have the old data exist

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Docker compose generates anonymous volumes for MongoDB image container, you should bind `/data/db` and `/data/configdb` like this:

```
version: "3"
services: 
  db:
    image: mongo:4.0.6
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
      - mongodb-config:/data/configdb

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
  mongodb-config:
```

In general, if you want to prevent to some DB image container generates anonymous volumes, you can run on command line `docker inspect <container-name>` or `docker container inspect <container-name>`, then look for **Mounts** object and see the **destination** key/value to know what to bind on docker-compose definition